# Error after updating XCode, NativeScript-socketio?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

recently updated my Macbook to Big Sur 11.4, and updated my xcode to 12.5.1. I'm not sure if this is what has caused it, however my app does not seem to run anymore. It compiles, but when I run
tns debug ios
It transfers to the simulator, opens, then crashes immediately with the below error:

```
CONSOLE LOG file: node_modules/nativescript-vue-devtools/index.js:75:24: TypeError: this.socket.connect is not a function. (In 'this.socket.connect()', 'this.socket.connect' is undefined)
***** Fatal JavaScript exception - application has been terminated. *****
Native stack trace:
1   0x11054502e NativeScript::reportFatalErrorBeforeShutdown(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::Exception*, bool)
2   0x110585e18 NativeScript::FFICallback<NativeScript::ObjCMethodCallback>::ffiClosureCallback(ffi_cif*, void*, void**, void*)
3   0x110f815a2 ffi_closure_unix64_inner
4   0x110f81fca ffi_closure_unix64
5   0x11401178a __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__
6   0x11401127c __CFRunLoopDoTimer
7   0x11401081a __CFRunLoopDoTimers
8   0x11400ae69 __CFRunLoopRun
9   0x11400a1a7 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
10  0x11e3ccd85 GSEventRunModal
11  0x115bae4df -[UIApplication _run]
12  0x115bb339c UIApplicationMain
13  0x110f81e0d ffi_call_unix64
14  0x139f2c250
JavaScript stack trace:
srcBackendJs(file:///app/vendor.js:56126:2296)
at __webpack_require__(file: app/webpack:/webpack/bootstrap:19:0)
at file: app/webpack:/webpack/bootstrap:83:0
at ../node_modules/@vue/devtools/build/backend.js(file:///app/vendor.js:52613:88)
at __webpack_require__(file: app/webpack/bootstrap:750:0)
at fn(file: app/webpack/bootstrap:120:0)
at connect(file: node_modules/@vue/devtools/index.js:17:12)
at setupDevtools(file: node_modules/nativescript-vue-devtools/index.js:63:23)
at invoke(file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/timer/timer.ios.js:54:53)
at file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/timer/timer.ios.js:18:12
at UIApplicationMain([native code])
at run(file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/application/application.ios.js:312:26)
at file: node_modules/nativescript-vue/dist/index.js:12597:2
at file: node_modules/nativescript-vue-devtools/index.js:92:25
at file:///app/bundle.js:21747:10
at ./main.js(file:///app/bundle.js:21751:34)
at __webpack_require__(file: app/webpack/bootstrap:750:0)
at checkDeferredModules(file: app/webpack/bootstrap:43:0)
at webpackJsonpCallback(file: app/webpack/bootstrap:30:0)
at anonymous(file:///app/bundle.js:2:61)
at evaluate([native code])
at moduleEvaluation([native code])
at [native code]
at asyncFunctionResume([native co<…>
JavaScript error:
file:///app/vendor.js:56126:2296: JS ERROR TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'socket.on')
***** Fatal JavaScript exception - application has been terminated. *****
Native stack trace:
1   0x11054502e NativeScript::reportFatalErrorBeforeShutdown(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::Exception*, bool)
2   0x110596f94 -[TNSRuntime executeModule:referredBy:]
3   0x10f714653 main
4   0x114926bbd start
JavaScript stack trace:
UIApplicationMain(file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/application/application.ios.js:312:26)
at run(file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/application/application.ios.js:312:26)
at file: node_modules/nativescript-vue/dist/index.js:12597:2
at file: node_modules/nativescript-vue-devtools/index.js:92:25
at file:///app/bundle.js:21747:10
at ./main.js(file:///app/bundle.js:21751:34)
at __webpack_require__(file: app/webpack/bootstrap:750:0)
at checkDeferredModules(file: app/webpack/bootstrap:43:0)
at webpackJsonpCallback(file: app/webpack/bootstrap:30:0)
at anonymous(file:///app/bundle.js:2:61)
at evaluate([native code])
at moduleEvaluation([native code])
at [native code]
at asyncFunctionResume([native code])
at [native code]
at promiseReactionJob([native code])
JavaScript error:
file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/application/application.ios.js:312:26: JS ERROR Error
(CoreFoundation) *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NativeScript encountered a fatal error: Error
at
UIApplicationMain(file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/application/application.ios.js:312:26)
at run(file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/application/application.ios.js:312:26)
at file: node_modules/nativescript-vue/dist/index.js:12597:2
at file: node_modules/nativescript-vue-devtools/index.js:92:25
at file:///app/bundle.js:21747:10
at ./main.js(file:///app/bundle.js:21751:34)
at __webpack_require__(file: app/webpack/bootstrap:750:0)
at checkDeferredModules(file: app/webpack/bootstrap:43:0)
at webpackJsonpCallback(file: app/webpack/bootstrap:30:0)
at anonymous(file:///app/bundle.js:2:61)
at evaluate([native code])
at moduleEvaluation([native code])
at [native code]
at asyncFunctionResume([native code])
at [native code]
at promiseReactionJob([native code])
', reason: '(null)'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001140a2fba __exceptionPreprocess + 242
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000113f57ff5 objc_exception_throw + 48
2   NativeScript                        0x000000011054556f _ZN12NativeScript30report<…>
NativeScript caught signal 6.
Native Stack:
1   0x110595be1 sig_handler(int)
2   0x7fff60335d7d _sigtramp
3   0xffff00001fa5
4   0x114a5bcb5 abort
5   0x11475b692 abort_message
6   0x11474cdfd demangling_unexpected_handler()
7   0x113f3dace _objc_terminate()
8   0x11475aaa7 std::__terminate(void (*)())
9   0x11475d174 __cxa_get_exception_ptr
10  0x11475d13b __cxxabiv1::exception_cleanup_func(_Unwind_Reason_Code, _Unwind_Exception*)
11  0x113f58119 objc_exception_throw
12  0x11054556f NativeScript::reportFatalErrorBeforeShutdown(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::Exception*, bool)
13  0x110596f94 -[TNSRuntime executeModule:referredBy:]
14  0x10f714653 main
15  0x114926bbd start
JS Stack:
```

It seems to be something to do with NativeScript-SocketIo? The following is the offending code, but it is in vendor.js

```
  Common.prototype.connect = function () {
    this.socket.connect();
  };

  Common.prototype.disconnect = function () {
    this.socket.disconnect();
  };

  return Common;
}();
```